# Anime set in a world where females choose their gender

Tags: simoun

I remember seeing this title on Anime News Network but I can not for the life of me remember the name.

The Plot Summary I remember from the site is that in the world all humans are born as female and remain like that until a certain age in which they have to choose their gender.

The staring group have been tasked with an important mission of some sorts and i think their equipment can only be used by females as i remember the summary saying that the group are at the age where they must choose their gender but it's been decided that they can delay the decision for the duration of their mission.

I know it isn't Infinite Stratos as the plot didn't describe a guy who is able to use female equipment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am very sure it is [Simoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simoun_%28anime%29), everything say matches.

[image]

> In the world of Daikuuriku, everyone is born female, and chooses which sex they wish to become at age 17. In this world, the peaceful theocracy of Simulacrum is guarded by magical flying machines called "Simoun", which can only be piloted by young girls who haven't chosen a sex yet. The Simoun can activate a magical power known as "Ri Maajon" that can destroy large numbers of enemies at once. When the industrialized nation of Argentum decides that it needs to invade Simulacrum to acquire the secret of the Simoun, war breaks out, drawing the Simoun "Sibyllae" (priestesses who fly the Simoun) into a lopsided battle. Because the war is raging, the Sibyllae are granted an exemption from choosing a permanent sex for as long as they're willing to keep flying. Aaeru, a determined young Sibylla with a mysterious past, and Neviril, the leader of Chor Tempest, Simulacrum's most elite Simoun squadron, must lead their fellow priestesses through conflict both within their ranks and in the sky.

Comment: Ahh yes, that's it, the Plot Summary is right and matches all the points i mentioned (girls choosing their gender, the equipment (ship) that only girls can pilot, the group getting to hold off making their decision) and after seeing the Anime News Network page the memory of reading it came rushing back